# What if the speed of light were 100 times higher?

Tags: space, physics

Imagine the speed of light is 100 times that in our universe. Light from the moon takes about 1/100th of a second, the sunlight reaches our eyes in about 4 seconds, from nearby Alpha Centauri in about 16 days, and from the galactic center in about 260 years.

Assuming the laws of relativity would be scaled up to the higher value of $c$, would that make it easier to travel to other worlds?

Besides being awesome, would there be any other important considerations that I should keep in mind?

*Edit: In light of the first few responses, if at all possible, I would like to assume scenarios where the universe does not burn down horribly. But perhaps such a fast propagation of causality leaves me with no outs...*

Comment: With my short story character's luck, I've probably just destroyed her universe.

Comment: Energy per unit of mass would be quite a lot larger (E=mc^2). I don't know the implications of this, except maybe that WWII would have ended the world.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh Or perhaps in that universe the formula is E=mc^2/100 :)

Comment: And perhaps E=fish :D

Comment: Added bonus: MMORPG latency times go way donw.

Comment: This sounds like a perfect questions for XKCD's "What If" blog.

Comment: Although yes c is linked to other constants in physics, it is at least feasible to consider changing it in a fantasy setting without obeying *all* the real linkages as-is. It may even be feasible in real physics by changing other constants (e.g. fine structure constant) or by inserting some fudge-factors. I think it is worth figuring out nice abstraction points where you could keep some physics the same.

Comment: @SerbanTanasa I think you mean E=(mc^2)/10000, or E=m(c/100)^2

Comment: Is this a universe that originally had `c` then through some magic turned to `100c` or has it always been `100c`? If the former, given the number of stuffs in physics that are related to `c`, I would be very surprised if not everything blows up horribly. If the latter, then I'd suspect probably there won't be much change, everything will just scale to match.

Comment: @LieRyan The difference would be in things that are not linear with respect to `c` - and that's actually quite a few. Many are actually relative, though - say, the conversion between gravitational potential and kinetic energy will stay the same, because the `c` factor is the same on both sides (assuming general relativity is correct, of course). Strength of materials? Maybe bigger. However, there's also the question of *why* the relation between `c` and, say, strength of the EM force, exists - will the constant stay `newC / 100`, or will it be bigger?

Comment: Maybe all distanses (including atom sizes) would be proportionally higher, so no noticable effects would be visible?

Comment: Well, holding all the other physical constants the same, you'd seem to run into some issues with a larger value of `c` ripping the universe apart. You seem to be only concerned with travel time and/or the universe's "speed limit" ... so why not simply imagine that "the speed of light" is not the universe's speed limit?  Or why not adjust some (or all) of the other physical constants upwards to compensate?  Or, simpler yet, imagine that cosmological distances are 2 orders of magnitude smaller?  (Maybe cosmological inflation is smaller in your universe, so things are closer to each other.)

Comment: *Real* physicists uses c = 1 (or rather [c ≡ 1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_units)), so nothing really changes.

Comment: @DaaaahWhoosh Energy = Force * Current * Speed * Height? No, we can show from dimensional analysis that that can't be it, the units are all wrong. Kg m^2 / s^2 vs Kg C m^3 / s^4

Comment: Physicists would say it's not physically meaningful to talk about changes in a constant with units like distance/time, you can only talk about changes in [dimensionless constants](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/constants.html). The problem with changing the speed of light alone is that this will change the nature of any force involving the speed of light like electromagnetism, which will also change the length of rulers made out of particles bounded by that force and so on. See [this answer on the physics stack exchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/176296/59406) for details.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

If you say you want to make the speed of light 100 times as high, you have to say what you want to keep constant. I'll assume you want to keep constant the sizes of things (because if light is 100 times as fast, but all things are 100 times as large, the apparent speed is again the same), and also keep the time scales of physical processes (again, because if light goes 100 times as fast, but you also live 100 times as fast, you've won nothing).

## Summary

I think by carefully adjusting the constants, you could make it so that *most* things stay more or less the same. However, there will be inevitable changes in the details, especially forget about earth magnetic field (and associated effects, like polar lights), permanent magnets, magnetic hard disks, golden gold and liquid mercury.

**Edit:** As Peter Cordes mentioned in the comments, also a lot of electric technology (especially motors and generators, as well as coils for circuits) depend on magnetic fields. This would have negatively affected all electric technology, and might result in a steampunk-like world (because steam engines obviously don't rely on magnetic fields).

## How would physics have to be changed?

Let's first start with Maxwell's equations, which actually determine the speed of light [note: I'll use SI units throughout; some argumentations would have to be adapted for other unit systems, because they have less constants into which to incorporate the effects, but the ultimate effects would of course be the same].

In Maxwell's equations, there are two constants, $\epsilon_0$ which effectively determines the strength of an electric field generated by a charge density $\rho$ via the source equation
$$\operatorname{div} \vec E = \rho/\epsilon_0$$
and $\mu_0$ which effectively determines the strength of the magnetic field generated by a current density $\vec j$ via
$$\operatorname{curl} \vec B=\mu_0 \vec j$$
(note that unlike in the electric case this is not the complete Maxwell equation).

Maxwell's equations (the parts which I omitted above) predict electromagnetic waves going with the speed
$$c = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon_0\mu_0}}$$
So you see, to modify the speed of light, you have to modify either the electric or the magnetic field a charge/current generates. For example, you could reduce both electromagnetic constants by a factor 1/100; that would make electric fields 100 times as strong (remember, $\epsilon_0$ is in the denominator of the source equation) and magnetic fields 1/100 as strong. Alternatively you could leave $\epsilon_0$ unchanged, but apply a factor 1/10000 to $\mu_0$, thus only (massively) weakening all magnetic fields, or vice versa, making electric fields much stronger but leaving magnetic fields unchanged. Indeed, you could even make one of them larger while reducing the other even more at the same time. So you see we have a certain freedom here, which we have to solve in another way.

So let's now look at the condition that sizes should remain the same. Well, the relevant size is, of course, the size of atoms, which basically can be written in terms of the Bohr radius,
$$a_0 = \frac{4\pi\epsilon_0\hbar^2}{m_e e^2}$$
where $m_e$ is the electron's mass, $e$ is its charge, and $\hbar$ is Planck's (reduced) constant. This, of course, means we've got yet another constant we can play with, so this alone won't help us. So let's look at the second condition, that time scales also should be kept constants. Now quantum mechanics tells us that time scales are given by $\hbar/E$ where $E$ is an energy scale; for atomic processes (and thus also for chemistry and thus life) the relevant energy scale is given by the Rydberg energy,
$$Ry = \frac{e^2}{2(4\pi\epsilon_0)a_0}$$
That means, the time scale can be characterized by
$$\tau = \frac{2\hbar(4\pi\epsilon_0)a_0}{e^2}$$
If we want to keep both $a_0$ and $\tau$ (that is, sizes and time scales) constant, we need to keep both $\hbar$ and $\epsilon_0$ unchanged. Remembering the discussion above, this means we have to give $\mu_0$ a factor of $10000$.

## So what would be the result?

The most direct change would be that magnetic fields would be *much* weaker, by a factor of 10000. Basically, **forget about the magnetic field of earth.** Also, forget about permanent magnets; they will be too weak to be of any use.  Also, magnetic storage will probably not be a feasible way to store information. Actually, given that the very existence of ferromagnetism depends on sufficiently strong magnetic interaction, I'm not sure if there would be *any* ferromagnetism; if it existed, it would be a low-temperature phenomenon.

For further effects, let's look at the most important constant in electromagnetism: The fine structure constant,
$\alpha = \frac{e^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0\hbar c}$
Since the only constant which changes is $c$, this would mean that $\alpha$ is only 1/100 as large as in our world. Which is not that surprising, given that the name of that constant comes from its relevance for the atomic fine structure, which is caused by relativistic effects. With a higher speed of light, of course you expect relativistic effects to be reduced. Note that the dominant energies in atoms would *not* be changed (that's a direct consequence from neither $\hbar$ nor the relevant time scales being changed).

Well, given this, we come to a very visible (and surprising) effect of a much higher speed of light:

**Gold would [no longer be golden!](http://hindi-1914.blogspot.de/2007/11/relativity-in-chemistry-color-of-gold.html)**

And moreover, mercury would no longer be liquid either. Note that relativistic effects are important mostly for heavy elements, so the properties of the most important elements for life (especially hydrogen, oxygen, nitrogen and carbon) should not be substantially changed; life would probably not be affected.

However I'm not sure what it would do with nuclear physics which is much more dominated by relativistic effects; mass defects would certainly be much more pronounced, but it might possibly alter the whole nuclear stability properties. On the other hand, one might evade that problem by adjusting some other fundamental constants relevant for nuclear physics.

Since the energy scales would be kept constant, $E=mc^2$ would mean a 10000-fold increase of the energy per mass; so a matter-antimatter annihilation would increase correspondingly. Whether nuclear processes also show this additional energy would again depend on the adjustments to nuclear physics; my bet would be that if you make them so that the stable isotopes remain the same, you'd also get approximately the same energy out of your nuclear processes. But that's just a guess; I don't know enough about nuclear physics to really say.

Given that in General Relativity, energy and momentum are the source of gravitation, a higher energy would also imply stronger gravitation; however you've got yet again a constant you can modify to avoid this: Just make the gravitational constant smaller by an appropriate amount.

And of course, you'd only get relativistic effects at high speeds; that's after all the whole point of it. So you'd get fast communication over wide distances, and also possibly very fast space travel (although we are still far from even reaching relativistic speeds for spaceships within our "slow-light" universe).

Comment: The size of macroscopic stuff scales with the lengths of bonds between atoms, and crystal structure.  This presumably scales the same way as the Bohr atom radius with changing $\epsilon_0$.  It's not hard to imagine the possibility of atoms getting "bigger" but not farther apart, as macroscopic stuff has a lot of empty space.  (Or am I mixing up the "lots of empty space" thing being only when you count electrons and nuclei as taking space, not whole atoms? (i.e. electron shells / orbitals / probability densities))

Comment: @Peter Cordes: "Or am I mixing up the "lots of empty space" thing being only when you count electrons and nuclei as taking space, not whole atoms?" Yes. If you look at a scanning tunnelling microscope image of a surface, you'll see that the atoms are densely packed. Indeed, covalent bonding depends on the atomic orbitals to overlap (so that electrons can be "shared" between atoms). And so does electric conductance of metals (so that valence electrons can move freely from one atom to another).

Comment: The 10k reduction in $\mu_0$ would make electric motors far less efficient, as FAR larger currents would be needed to produce the same force.  Similarly, turbine generators would have huge problems.  (unless there were materials with extremely high permeability to use as cores).  Electronics would also have a hard time with inductors that are 10k times weaker (again, unless ferromagnetic materials had higher relative permeability, so the permeability or susceptibility of cores decreased by a lot less than 10k.)  LC circuits could potentially use MUCH larger capacitors, or higher freq...

Comment: We might need superconductors to make useful motors and generators at all.  IIRC, though, the current you can induce into a superconducting ring could be limited by something other than the maximum magnetic field, so you might not be able to crank $H$ up as high as in our universe, because you'd hit a different limit before hitting the critical magnetic field strength.  Maybe you just need more loops.  It's weird to think about a superconducting loop carrying 10k times the current but with the same stored energy as in our world.

Comment: found a link which confirms what I thought I remembered: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superconductivity#Elementary_properties_of_superconductors says that superconductors have a critical current density, as well as a critical temp and magnetic field, above which they aren't superconductors.  So the critical current density could be a big obstacle to making superconducting magnets strong enough to do anything.

Comment: The industrial revolution might never have had an electrical component, on a world with 10k lower $\mu_0$.  Steam turbines and internal combustion would work the same, though.  Probably power grids would be in the form of pipes carrying some kind of fuel, rather than wires carrying electricity.  I'm not sure what kind of non-magnetic electricity generation we'd use once we discovered electronics.  Maybe fuel cells, flow batteries, or photovoltaics.

Comment: @PeterCordes: You raise some good points. So in short, a higher speed of light would result in a steampunk world. That's an interesting aspect! However the critical current in superconductors [is because of the critical magnetic field](http://www.open.edu/openlearn/science-maths-technology/engineering-and-technology/engineering/superconductivity/content-section-2.5) and thus would be correspondingly higher.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I've now added something about that effect into my summary.

Comment: Ah, thanks for clearing that up about superconductors.  I couldn't remember if the $I_c$ was from magnetic effects, or from running out of cooper pairs or something.  re:steampunk.  Internal combustion would work just as well, but sure, steampunk is cooler than diesel cars.  (spark plugs are powered by alternators.  Or batteries..).  With high-speed electronics, we can crank the frequency high enough for transformers with lots of turns to work fine.  But motors/generators with a frequency based on something physically moving will still have problems.

Comment: Without the magnetic field, wouldn't Earth not be protected from space radiation? Then, there couldn't be humans, or much life (at least life as we know it). Is this true?

Comment: One other surprising effect--your car won't start.  Without relativistic effects your standard lead-acid cell puts out a much lower voltage.

Comment: Thought here--nuclear binding energy.  I'm completely unable to convince myself that this isn't going to mess with the binding energy curve, but I'm out of my depth in figuring out what it's going to do.  The problem is when you mess with that curve you mess with the element distribution.  Earth has so much iron because it's at the bottom of the curve and everything beyond it can only come from neutron capture.  Move it to the left and iron becomes much less common.  Move it to the right and the stars burn farther along the table, again iron is much less common.

Answer (score 45):

The speed of light is a squared constant in $e=mc^2$, so multiplying it by 100 means atomic reactions — nuclear bombs and plants, and solar fusion — will be approximately **10,000** times more powerful.  I suspect that this would either:

1. Make it impossible for a star's gravity to hold it together against its fusion core unless it's super-massive.
2. Or make it so stars expand more (greater internal pressure from fusion vs the constriction force of gravity).

Either of which would probably make our form of life impossible.  Certainly our solar system wouldn't exists in its current form.

Comment: I recently heard a talk where the speaker mentioned a technology being thought of which utilizes the blast from atomic or hydrogen bombs being fired behind the spaceship to accelerate the ship. If one could use this technique, I guess that higher velocities should be possible in such a world.

Comment: @InvisiblePanda: the speaker was probably referencing [Project Orion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Orion_%28nuclear_propulsion%29) project (not to be confused with the contemporary, capsule project of the same name). Regardless, as this answer correctly implies, you have to have an intelligent life capable of building such a ship in the first place.

Comment: @TheTerribleSwiftTomato Ah yes, that might be it. And yes, you're right, I just had to think about this project when I read about the more powerful reactions, so I dropped a comment. It should be covered with the 'If one could use' part though as this is clearly only possible if there 'is one' ;-)

Comment: Or make it so stars expand a bit more, and fuse a lot slower. (Could Earth be closer to the sun to compensate for the sun's reduced output?)

Comment: -1 Actually it would make all known element unstable. Physics would be VERY VERY different. I doubt that stars would even form. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-structure_constant

Comment: Our form of life impossible?  Depends on how you think of our form of life.  If you think of humans as sentient puddles that formed to fit a pothole in the road then contemplating potholes with different shapes seems less likely to preclude our existence.  http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/70827-this-is-rather-as-if-you-imagine-a-puddle-waking

Comment: Or it means that these reactions have 10,000 times less change in mass. We're talking about binding energy, not the rest energy of protons and neutrons - this isn't antimatter.

Comment: This is backwards. The strength of nuclear reactions is not set by $E = mc^2$, but rather the _amount to which they affect mass_ is set thereby. The energies involved are based on the relative strengths of and balances between the forces operating within a nucleus - namely the competition between the residual strong and electromagnetic interactions (and to a lesser extent, the weak interaction which powers beta decays). If the strengths of these forces remain the same, the result is not that nuclear reactions become 10,000x more powerful, but that they only change masses 1/10,000 as much.

Comment: @InvisiblePanda The question is whether Orion can get you into space in the first place.  There's no question the drive would work, the question is how fast you can accelerate without melting your pusher plate--and whether you can attain orbit is questionable.

Answer (score 22):

**Would that make it easier to travel to other worlds?**

In terms of regular (rocket powered) space-flight, I don't think so. The distances between stars are so huge that the amount of fuel we need to *approach* speeds where special relativity becomes important is much, much, larger than the spaceship itself.

A quick Wikipedia search on [Lorentz factor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_factor#Numerical_values) shows that you need to get to ~87% of the speed of light before time appears to slowed by half.

With the current speed of light, to get to that speed, a 100 tonne spaceship will need [9.2 million, million, GJ of energy](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=kinetic%20energy%20of%20100%20tonne%20mass%20travelling%20at%200.87c).

If you were to bump up *c* by a factor of 100, you should be able to ignore Lorentz factors. Instead, you'd only need 3.4 million, million GJ. I have no idea what that is in practical terms, but I expect it's still a lot.

**would there be any other important considerations that I should keep in mind?**

Magnetic and/or electric fields would be influenced as well. The speed of light is can be expressed as the result of other fundamental constants in nature; [the permeability and the permittivity of space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_wave_equation). Because these are all related, you'll have to change one (or both) of these too.

That will effect motors, and electronics. I won't comment on *how* they will effect them. As I really can't grok the physics behind it.

Comment: Since somebody mentioned nuclear propulsion in another comment - according to George Dysons book on Project Orion it was estimated that it would have taken some 25 million bombs (with yields between 5 and 15 kilotons) to get to the nearest star with in a human lifetime, and that number does not include braking (so you'd just woosh by) or the journey back. As you say that would indeed be a lot of fuel to carry.

Comment: c is a factor in the equation that determines the energy output of a given nuclear warhead, though, so Project Orion's bomb-powered craft just had its thrust increased by a huge amount, which would reduce the number of bombs you'd have to carry...

Comment: *"Instead, you'd only need 3.4 million, million GJ. I have no idea what that is in practical terms"* [1 kWh = 3.6 MJ](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kilowatt_hour#Definition). Thus, if my powers of ten are not off, 3.4e12 GJ = 3.4e15 MJ = 3.4e15 kWh ~ 390,000 GW *continuous* for one full year. 9.2e12 GJ is almost three times that at right about one million gigawatts continuous for one year. The 2008 world energy consumption (all sources) was about 144,000 TWh (about 16400 GW continuous) says Wikipedia. So even your lower figure is about 24 times global energy consumption.

Comment: @anaximander, the practial limit to the yield for Orion bombs  is what ship and crew can absorb (this is the reason to consider 5KT bombs even when much bigger yields where available). So I'm not sure how much an Orion-Type craft would benefit from the changed physics.

Comment: @anaximander, _c_ more correctly is a factor of the mass-equivalence of energy. How much energy is *released* from a nuclear reaction is determined by the mass-_change_ before and after.

Comment: I've done some crude calculations and simulations of this in the past, and a fusion powered spaceship would struggle to get to 10% c, and that's with something like a 1000:1 fuel to payload ratio w/ multiple stages. Of course if c was 100 times higher, you'd get 10,000 times the energy out of that fuel, so you could go 100 times faster. You could travel to the nearest star in a few years, or even months. Assuming the star somehow isn't blown apart by that same super-energetic fusion.

Comment: @EikePierstorff They would benefit because this change doesn't just let you make the same size bomb and get more bang, it also lets you make a much smaller bomb and get the same bang. So, while they might not get any more thrust *per bomb*, the bombs they're getting it from are about 10,000 times smaller. They use 4 orders of magnitude less material to make, and require 4 orders of magnitude less fuel-tank space on the ship.

Answer (score 13):

Radiation would be more energetic. Visible light (~1000 nanometres) would be as dangerously ionizing as X-ray radiation is on earth (~10 nanometres). UV light would be like gamma rays. You'd need some really intense sun-block to walk outdoors.

Not exactly sure how the eyes' photoreceptors work, but it could be that the visible light photons would be too energetic and would just pass right through without being captured, and you might instead be seeing in entirely different far-infrared wavelengths instead. Either that, or you'd still see in visible light, but the brightness would seem WAY higher.

Seems like so many of these questions end with "you'd see a really lovely light show, and then die in a really horrible way".

Comment: Rats! So either we're stuck at a measly 300,000km/s or we blow up all the stars? It's just not fair.

Comment: This plays well with my idea that all distances are proportionally larger. Visible light would have wavelength 100 times longer.

Comment: You would, indeed, be unable to see what is currently known as "visible light", *if* you define that term by frequency. If you define it by wavelength, you'd still be seeing that same wavelength of light. However, that light that is now the same wavelength as real-world visible light is, for frequency-based definitions, in the UV direction, not towards the IR. Not that you'd be seeing actual UV, by frequency-based definitions, you'd be well beyond that range, and into the x-ray portion of the spectrum.

Comment: Good call on the wavelength/frequency issue. Now I want to know which one our rods and cones care about. I suspect probably wavelength, because apertures... no clue how to test that though. If both are relevant (say, if we need the light to fit through a certain aperture, but also to have a certain energy so's not to just pass right through the receptor) then we might be blind. Thinking about it, the light would refract differently through our lenses, too, wouldn't it?

Comment: I think more likely the organic compounds that have their electrons affected by photons "care about" photon energy.  Depending on which physical constants change to produce the change in the speed of light, your photoreceptors might or might not be tuned to a higher energy.  celtschk's answer makes a good case for keeping $\epsilon_0$ fixed, and just letting $\mu_0$ change, which should mean same frequency = same energy.  (and the scales of time and space don't change, either.)  Wavelengths would get longer by a factor of 100, but that's still far smaller than the diameter of a pupil.

Comment: Probably larger than the photoreceptive cell, though.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not physicist so I might be wrong, but I don't think the other answers are correct.

In fact, I think that *if the speed of light suddenly got 100 times higher, absolutely nothing would change*. We even might not be able to realize it has changed.

In our daily lives we perceive space and time as two separate things; but in reality, they are the same exact thing, called spacetime. Everything in the universe, including light and ourselves, *always* move through spacetime at c, the speed of light.

Space and time are however orthogonal, and this allows us to move in either as different speeds, *as long as the total spacetime travel speed is always `c`*; never less, never more.

So, if you are not moving through space or moving very slowly (like ourselves) you move through time at near the speed of light. If you travel at near the speed of light, you don't travel through time. (Light never travels through time, and thus only travels through space at maximum speed, c; this happens because it has no mass)

With all that said, if c was 100 times higher, time would also be 100 times as fast for us. The chemical reactions in our brain would happen more quickly; but this means we will think "faster" so I don't think we would even realize it.

Some other answers said  atomic bombs and stuff like that would be much more powerful. But is it true? I don't think so; more energy is released, but in much less time as time is quicker, so it would feel exactly the same.

In short, I am not a physicist and I may be wrong, but from my understanding `c` is a constant that affects everything, and thus if it increases or decreases *everything* increases or decreases with it leading to no observable changes. In fact - from my understanding - it could even be constantly changing and we would have no way to know.

In fact, thinking of it a bit more, it's just not possible to say that c = c * 100. Since c is m/s, if it travels 100 times more meters, time will be 100 times quicker; so it becomes c = 100m / 100s which has no change.

Comment: From a physicist: you're wrong. (Sorry to be blunt!) Or more precisely, it sounds like you're talking about the situation where the scale of spacetime has been increased by 100. You're right about certain things not changing in that case, but that's not what the question asks.

Comment: @DavidZ and OP Good points, I'll have to ponder that for a while. Could it be that attempting to change c would alter all dimensions of the Minkowski space?

Comment: No, it just alters the ratio between the space and time dimensions. It also alters lots of other physical effects that depend on that ratio.

Comment: If the speed of light did not affect anything, no one would ever be able to measure it.

Comment: @EmilioMBumachar You're looking at this from a different POV - `c` is speed, that is distance per time. If the space time changes while preserving the ratio of distance per time, speed of light will remain the same. That's basically what *spacetime* is talking about. However, as DavidZ noted, while `c` would stay the same, some other things will not - because, in a way, the *units* changed - but we can only measure the *ratio* (because to use, the units aren't some absolute values, we can only measure them in relative terms).

Comment: Your 100m/100s is not the same as 100m/s. The latter would be "a hundred times faster" (which the question asks about), while the former is "everything scaled up by a factor of 100" (which as other comments have said, is what you answered).

Comment: Also, with a bomb, if you release more energy, *and* you do it faster, those don't cancel out, they're a two-fer. Both of them result in increasing the intensity of the blast.

Comment: I think this could be improved to show that if the fine structure constant remained unchanged, you would see no difference.

Answer (score 2):

Suddenly computer networks and computers in general can be made a lot faster (or at least networks can have less latency).

Comment: Fibre optics I can see being faster, would standard electronic circuits go any faster though?

Comment: @TimB It poses a limit that we are not too far away from. I am computer scientist, but no expert in hardware. My educated guess is: yes, at least it opens up the potential.

Comment: Not very constructive...

Comment: @DustinJackson I think this qualifies as an "important consideration" per the asker's last sentence.

Comment: @DustinJackson Now that I think about it, although the effects may not be so great on earth (I think they would, but nvm), suddendly we can communicate a lot better with our spacecraft and potential space colonies. If the earth-moon is suddenly only 0.01 seconds, we can basically just attach it to the Internet (still not great latency, but way better!). Mars' closest distance is 3 lightminutes, max. distance is 21 light-minutes. Suddenly you have a round-trip time of something like 3-20 seconds, not great, but hey!

Comment: The extra speed might give you time to read Tweets about the now rapidly expanding, all engulfing Sun!

Comment: This would, indeed, allow things like computer processors to go very much faster. This was a big part of the issues behind the gigachip wars back in the day. This is also why pre-gigachip-wars, the clock speed of a chip was pretty much proportional to the rate at which they completed calculations (so, for example, a 400MHz chip took about twice as long as an 800MHz one for the same job), but current chips, despite being in the 4GHz range, are a ***lot*** more than 4 times faster than the old 1GHz chips.

Comment: @TimB: The delay between applying a voltage at one end of a wire, and seeing the voltage change at the other end, is proportional to the speed of light.  (given the dielectric constant of typical insulators, and the inductance of a straight cable, about 2/3rd the speed of light in a typical co-ax cable.)  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electrical_length#Velocity_factor

Answer (score 2):

Having looked it up, my understanding is now the expected result is stars would burn faster, releasing more energy.

Increasing the speed of light appears (perhaps it doesn't have to be this way--hard to say) to decrease the binding energies at the same ratio so reactions drive normally; however the consequence of a higher speed of light is nuclear reactions run faster at the same energy levels, and energy from gravity wells doesn't change so fast.

This yields hotter stars in smaller sizes. KSP anybody?

Comment: I would love to see your working on that; binding energy had crossed my mind, but I know very little on it, and didn't get far with Wikipedia.

Comment: It appears from the nuclear binding energy setup that the energy is the active term and the mass change is the result from that. I'm sorry, but there really can never be any more than that. A more sophisticated answer will mean the same.

Comment: Wouldn't that be hotter starts with lower *masses*? Stars exist in an equilibrium between gravitational pressure and the pressure from the fusion-generated heat. So if mass remained constant, and so did gravitational force (big if, of course), the volume of the star would have to increase, and its surface temperature would go down. So same mass, more energy output, but more volume and a lower surface temperature.

Comment: Luaan: If you cross-compute for constant energy output (remember he doesn't want a disaster scenario if avoidable) you get lower mass which in turn means lower diameter. This increases the number of stars available for life.

Comment: I don't see them being actually any hotter. Yes, lower binding energy means easier, and thus faster, reaction rates, but remember, those same binding energies are where the energy output of the reaction comes from in the first place. It seems to me that you'd be burning through more atoms per second, but the total energy those atoms released would stay the same, because each individual atom reacted would yield less.

Comment: I held the binding energy invariant. The higher c directly increases the reaction rates.