# Doubling the Speed of Light

Tags: biology, physics

What would happen in a universe where  *c* was double what it is in ours? Based on the constants in our universe that allow life to exist on Earth in its current form/s (you can change a few if this is necessary), could Earth-based lifeforms exist? Of course this will involve changing at least one law of physics. I'm not inquiring about changing any particular law.  Ex. It would affect maximum rate of transfer of energy/information, which would increase the rate of osmosis, probably increase maximum rates of metabolism, which would increase maximum size of insects at our current oxygen levels, etc.

Comment: I'm not a physicists but I don't think you could do that. c has nothing to do with light but it's a speed of causality. If you keep fundamental constants same as ours, then by using Lorentz transformation c must be same as now. If you change them its anybody's guess life might not even exist https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=msVuCEs8Ydo

Comment: If the constant *c* was doubleed in your universe, and all physics remained the same, scientists would quickly find that the speed of light is *c* /2

Comment: The trouble is that the speed of light is linked with the elementary electric charge _e_ (the charge of the electron), the electric constant ε₀ (the permittivity of the vacuum), the Planck constant _ħ_ (the quantum of action) and the [fine-structure constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-structure_constant) α by the equation: _e²_ = 4παε₀ _ħc_. You cannot change only one of those; you must change at least two.

Comment: See http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/230703/do-we-know-why-there-is-a-speed-limit-in-our-universe/23083

Comment: You might find [these news articles](https://www.google.com/search?q=speed+of+light&num=100&safe=off&client=safari&hl=en-us&prmd=nvi&source=lnms&tbm=nws&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwig6uG1j47RAhXD6yYKHa_6BhgQ_AUIBygB&biw=1024&bih=649) interesting since they discuss new theories that the speed of light may not be a constant.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What if the speed of light were 100 times higher?](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10126/what-if-the-speed-of-light-were-100-times-higher)

Comment: I didn’t think it was *unclear*, but it’s a duplicate of http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10126/what-if-the-speed-of-light-were-100-times-higher or http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3646/can-i-keep-our-universe-but-without-the-speed-limit-of-light (thanks Separatrix)

Comment: Light actually have no speed... the constant 'c' is just the rate at which information is traveling, so I reckon calibrating it would produce a universe that is unrecognizable today.

Comment: @ThomBlairIII Variable lightspeed theories are not new. "Portuguese physicist João Magueijo first proposed superfast light in 1998 to explain the uniform temperature of the early universe. But because it contradicts Albert Einstein’s theory of special relativity, it never quite caught on." There are others. Look up variable lightspeed on Wikipedia.

Comment: @slobodan.blazeski c is the velocity of light in a vacuum. It has everything to with light. The constant c is linked to many physical phenomena. See AlexP's comment above. As for speed of causality, that is an artefact of the lightspeed limit. Change c, and physics changes. Creating toy universe like this can be a useful intellectual exercise. Sometimes it's good old-fashioned fun.

Comment: @Aify The OP doubled the speed of light, so the value of c in the fundamental constants will be half-lightspeed (assuming all other physics remains unchanged)..

Comment: @a4android «As for speed of causality, that is an artefact of the lightspeed limit.» you have that backwards. Particles with no inertia move as fast as possible in minkowski spacetime. Light is the first thing people noticed that has this property.

Comment: @a4android your remark to Aify above can’t work. *c* is the **only** speed that is lorentz invarient. The appearance of *c* in various physics formulas is an artefact of our units and dimensional analysis, and is commonly 1 in “natural units” systems.  You could not make light or anything else travel at twice that speed.

Comment: @JDługosz RE your comment RE my comment to Aify. I was pointing the parameters laid down by the OP about his question. This is about the alternative universe physics where lightspeed is twice our lightspeed and all other physics is the same as in our universe. Otherwise where c' = 2c the rest of physics has to rewritten. The OP wanted to keep physics the same. I was merely stating the obvious consequence of the question's parameters.

Comment: @JDługosz The speed of causality in any medium is the limiting velocity of that medium. In Minkowski spacetime that limiting velocity is the speed of light in a vacuum. Yes zero mass particles move at lightspeed. Yes light was the first example of Lorentz variance discovered. Unfortunately, your comment doesn't really enlighten me at all about how I got things backwards. Care to explain?

Comment: Causality is not *only* due to electromagnetic phenomina, so causality is not limited due to the speed of light.  Causality is more general, involving any quantum fields and spacetime curvature itself.  Light (etc.) is limited by the speed of causality.

Comment: @JDługosz I did my own research. What you're talking about is locality. I wasn't concerned with EM phenomena, but constant lightspeed one of the principles of relativity. The so-called speed of causality is better called the speed of causal interactions. Of the two versions of locality, we can each choose whichever one we prefer and both be right.

Comment: I'm not concerned about the processes leading to c being doubled, only the result...For instance, e=mc², so changing c changes the value of e...In the real world, what happens then?

Answer (score 4):

I know this has been explained **at length** before but I can’t find just where right now (**update:** Separatrix notes [Can I keep our universe, but without the speed limit (of light)?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3646/can-i-keep-our-universe-but-without-the-speed-limit-of-light) and [What if the speed of light were 100 times higher?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10126/what-if-the-speed-of-light-were-100-times-higher))

The speed of light is not simply a setting that can be changed. It relates to *everything* so for example electron orbitals would be different, bond strengths would be different, etc.  If you adjust other things as well to get the [fine structure constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-structure_constant) to still be the same, you find that everything is exactly the same!  Atoms are bigger and chemical reactions are slower, so all you did was change the scale of the universe.

So, in a universe where the speed of light was double, you would not have the same kind of atoms. You would not have the same *stuff* (stars, planets, galaxies), if you had rich structure at all.  So **no**, Earth based lifeforms could not exist.

Comment: I can only think of [these](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/3646/can-i-keep-our-universe-but-without-the-speed-limit-of-light) [two](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/10126/what-if-the-speed-of-light-were-100-times-higher?rq=1) immediately

Comment: This depends on what anyone means by Earth-based lifeforms. if the alternative universe in question permitted complex structures, then convergent evolution might, I say might, because nothing in this scenario is wholly certain, produce lifeforms resembling Earth-based organisms. Even their atoms are bigger and chemical reactions are slower.

Comment: Bigger/slower illustrates how nothing really changed: that is a different point. If you just change one or more things so *α* is different, then you will not *have* stars, planets, atoms as we understand them.  My review is brief because this has been explained at-length elsewhere.

Answer (score 3):

There's no real answer to this because we don't *know* what is required for life.  Our sample size is 1.  We do some extrapolation, but that's all we can do.  The thing is, we disagree on how to extrapolate.  Some argue that there are constants in the universe which, if they were different by a tiny fraction (I've heard one-part-per-million for some atomic forces), then the universe could not form atoms.  Others argue that life is a pattern which occurs in limitless variety, and that while the life may appear alien to us, it would crop up no matter how far the constants are from ours.

There's also an open question as to whether we are unique or not.  For all we know, you could restart the universe with *exactly* the same rules, but have the other team win a coin toss at the beginning of the universe and we find that tiny change lead in a direction which prevented life.  Or, for all we know, the humanoid lifeform pattern may truly be a eigenvector of how the universe functions, and we will end up with a new Earth for any initial state!

If you wanted to explore this further, my recommendation would be to look at the relationships with other key constants.  The constants in physics form a dense web of interconnections based on symmetries and other laws.  For example, Maxwell's equations for electromagnetic radiation show that $c=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\epsilon_0\mu_0}}$, tying the speed of light to the permittivity and permeability of the vacuum.  If the speed of light changes, so must one or both of these terms.  Since you're building the universe, you can choose how that change got distributed between those two terms, and look at their side effects.  Changing the permittivity, for instance, will likely affect the ability for air to act as an insulator, changing how lightning strikes.  Given that the some of the best theories for abiogenesis suggest life may have started when lighting struck the primordial soup, anything which changes the behavior of lightning has a change of affecting life as a whole!

Comment: Changing ε₀ will have massive effects on chemistry, for example -- all chemical forces are electric forces.

Comment: This is explained in more detail in [this answer](http://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/a/10280/885) by celtschk.

Answer (score 2):

Everything else fixed, one immediate consequence is that a fine structure constant becomes twice as small. [No carbon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-structure_constant#Anthropic_explanation), no life as we know it.

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question, I think everyone was thinking too in-depth.

Comment: Glad to see someone read the question and instead of flapdoodling around actually answered it. Plus one.