# What would happen if the speed of light were changed?

Tags: alternate-worlds

**In a gist, I'm curious to know whether or not a change of the speed of light would present any detrimental effects on the structure of the universe as we know it.**
Would stars and celestial superstructures in general form as usual, or would something in the math complicate those processes?
I want to say that the quantity and time of change are irrelevant, but I know I have some unknowns regarding the issue, so I will present those factors here: *c* is increased to ~3 billion kilometers per second; the time at which *c* is this speed is during the creation of the universe.

Comment: Well, are you asking about whether it changed during the lifetime of the universe, or simply whether it always was a universe with a different speed of light? The answer may be different for each scenario. Also, this might be a duplicate question; I think I found other similar questions while researching this topic, which I am also interested in.

Comment: Related: [What if the speed of light were 100 times higher?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/10126/32451)

Comment: @Inflationary_Bubble Let's go with the creation of. However, I did not think we knew enough about the creation of the universe to get any specific about it.

Comment: Also, I looked across this sight a bit to see if anyone discussed arbitrarily changing constant *c*. It seems I missed the link from @Alexander , which is an excellent suggestion by the way.

Comment: Well, on the question @Alexander linked, one answer did give a way - but it said that there would basically be no magnetic field for Earth. No one mentioned this, however, but I believe that without a magnetic field, Earth wouldn't be protected from radiation. I wrote a comment on that question just now, although I don't think anyone will notice it... I'm not sure whether there's another way to make it work.

Comment: _When_ does the change occur? Cause a 10,000x speed increase will have catastrophic effects on a new universe, circa big bang time.  But if it happened now?  Very different effects.

Comment: @Tim I will edit the question to answer your question.

Comment: Here's an interesting article: http://cds.cern.ch/record/618057/files/0305457.pdf